# How to get radius from visible area of MKmapview?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am able to get visible rectangle of map view and also centre point of map view and span deltas are also get from mkmaap view methods:
To get visible are :`mapView.visibleMapRect`  is used . To get centre point: `map view.centerCoordinate` is used and to get span: `mapView.region.span` is used.

Now I have all the information, how can i calculate radius of visible are using calculation? Can anyone explain me in detail?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578788/how-to-find-the-radius-of-visible-mkmapview-visible-screen-area) but the answer is giving me span not radius of visible area.

Answer (score 10):

To get the radius follow this:

```
- (CLLocationDistance)getRadius
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoor = [self getCenterCoordinate];
    // init center location from center coordinate
    CLLocation *centerLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:centerCoor.latitude longitude:centerCoor.longitude];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D topCenterCoor = [self getTopCenterCoordinate];
    CLLocation *topCenterLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:topCenterCoor.latitude longitude:topCenterCoor.longitude];

    CLLocationDistance radius = [centerLocation distanceFromLocation:topCenterLocation];

    return radius;
}
```

It will return the radius in **metres**.

To get center coordinate

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)getCenterCoordinate
{
    return [self.mapView centerCoordinate];
}
```

For getting radius, depends on where you want to get the 2nd point. Lets take the **Top Center**

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)getTopCenterCoordinate
{
    // to get coordinate from CGPoint of your map
    return [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(self.mapView.frame.size.width / 2.0f, 0) toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
}
```

Comment: For all swifties: a short extension for the MKMapView (here i'm using the topleft corner for radius:

`extension MKMapView{
    var topLeftCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D{
        return convert(CGPoint.zero, toCoordinateFrom: self)
    }
    
    var radius: CLLocationDistance{
        let centerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: centerCoordinate.latitude, longitude: centerCoordinate.longitude)
        let topLeftLocation = CLLocation(latitude: topLeftCoordinate.latitude, longitude: topLeftCoordinate.longitude)
        return centerLocation.distance(from: topLeftLocation)
    }
}`

Answer (score 10):

With **Swift 3.0** you can use extension to simplify your life:

```
extension MKMapView {

    func topCenterCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return self.convert(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.0, y: 0), toCoordinateFrom: self)
    }

    func currentRadius() -> Double {
        let centerLocation = CLLocation(coordinate: self.centerCoordinate)
        let topCenterCoordinate = self.topCenterCoordinate()
        let topCenterLocation = CLLocation(coordinate: topCenterCoordinate)
        return centerLocation.distance(from: topCenterLocation)
    }

}
```

With **Swift 4.0** :

```
extension MKMapView {

    func topCenterCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return self.convert(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.0, y: 0), toCoordinateFrom: self)
    }

    func currentRadius() -> Double {
        let centerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: self.centerCoordinate.latitude, longitude: self.centerCoordinate.longitude)
        let topCenterCoordinate = self.topCenterCoordinate()
        let topCenterLocation = CLLocation(latitude: topCenterCoordinate.latitude, longitude: topCenterCoordinate.longitude)
        return centerLocation.distance(from: topCenterLocation)
    }

}
```

Comment: **Swift 4**: Change `CLLocation(coordinate: *)` to `CLLocation(latitude: self.centerCoordinate.latitude, longitude: self.centerCoordinate.longitude)`

Comment: [Finn's Swift translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093843/how-to-get-radius-from-visible-area-of-mkmapview#comment71890373_29094530) works better