# [iOS]How could I get the latitudes/longitudes of top-left、bottom-right pixel？

Tags: swift, mkmapview

When I know the latitudes and longitudes of center, and how could I  get the latitudes and longitudes of top-left、top-right、bottom-right and bottom-left pxiel?

Fox example,it just like the picture:
[image]

How could I do with it?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following methods. basic idea taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44182763/2299040

```
extension MKMapView {

    func topLeftCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return convert(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), toCoordinateFrom: self)
    }

    func topRightCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        let x = frame.minX + frame.width
        return convert(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), toCoordinateFrom: self)
    }
    func bottomLeftCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        let y = frame.minY + frame.height
        return convert(CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), toCoordinateFrom: self)
    }

    func bottomRightCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        let x = frame.minX + frame.width
        let y = frame.minY + frame.height
        return convert(CGPoint(x: x, y: y), toCoordinateFrom: self)
    }
}
```