# How can I calculate the radius of the region visible in a MKMapView?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, quickblox

I'm using QuickBlox and I have a map that updates with users' locations.

I'm getting the users' locations and placing them on the map using the "QBRequest.geoDataWithFilter" function. 
I'm creating a filter that has a radius value. I'm also using the `mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)` function to detect when the region is changed.

The users' locations are updated regularly and they are being received from the server according to the User's location (the user that's logged in) **not the visible area** so I don't care about the center of the map.

**I want to be able to load more users in as I zoom out, so the radius should be increasing every time the user zooms out and decreasing in case he or she is zooming in**

How can I calculate the radius of the visible area on the map using the map's span? (I just need the equation if it's possible)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578788/how-to-find-the-radius-of-visible-mkmapview-visible-screen-area

Comment: Yeah I have seen this question, but the problem is that I require the radius in meters. That's how the geoDataWithFilter function works. Is it possible or should I look for another way?

Answer (score 2):

Its not radius what is required.

You need to use the region parameter from mapView.

Check out apple docs, it is pretty much clear from those.

Go thru this tutorial. It will help you a lot

[icode blog mapkit demo](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/12/21/introduction-to-mapkit-in-iphone-os-3-0/)

specifically you need to set something like this..

```
MKCoordinateSpan span = [self coordinateSpanWithMapView:self centerCoordinate:centerCoordinate andZoomLevel:zoomLevel];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span);
[self setRegion:region animated:animated];
```

where span can be calculated as

```
- (MKCoordinateSpan)coordinateSpanWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
                         centerCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)centerCoordinate
                             andZoomLevel:(NSUInteger)zoomLevel
{
// convert center coordiate to pixel space
double centerPixelX = [self longitudeToPixelSpaceX:centerCoordinate.longitude];
double centerPixelY = [self latitudeToPixelSpaceY:centerCoordinate.latitude];

// determine the scale value from the zoom level
NSInteger zoomExponent = 20 - zoomLevel;
double zoomScale = pow(2, zoomExponent);

// scale the map’s size in pixel space
CGSize mapSizeInPixels = mapView.bounds.size;
double scaledMapWidth = mapSizeInPixels.width * zoomScale;
double scaledMapHeight = mapSizeInPixels.height * zoomScale;

// figure out the position of the top-left pixel
double topLeftPixelX = centerPixelX - (scaledMapWidth / 2);
double topLeftPixelY = centerPixelY - (scaledMapHeight / 2);

// find delta between left and right longitudes
CLLocationDegrees minLng = [self pixelSpaceXToLongitude:topLeftPixelX];
CLLocationDegrees maxLng = [self pixelSpaceXToLongitude:topLeftPixelX + scaledMapWidth];
CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = maxLng - minLng;

// find delta between top and bottom latitudes
CLLocationDegrees minLat = [self pixelSpaceYToLatitude:topLeftPixelY];
CLLocationDegrees maxLat = [self pixelSpaceYToLatitude:topLeftPixelY + scaledMapHeight];
CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta = -1 * (maxLat - minLat);

// create and return the lat/lng span
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);
return span;
}
```